# How to extend Marlin to support additional movement axis?

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650, axis

On a RAMPS 1.4 it is possible to mount 5 stepper motors: `X`,`Y`,`Z` steppers are used for cartesian movements, while `E0` and `E1` are provided for extruders control.

I want to use `E0` and `E1` as additional movement axis in a robotical arm.

Is it possible in Marlin and if not, how can one approach the problem?

Comment: Klipper supports manual steppers natively, if that could be an option for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found many ways to re-task extruder steppers to 
behave like cartesian-like controls:

- If your application does not require contemporary movement of
  all axes, you can enable multiple extruders setting the `EXTRUDERS`
  define in Marlin's `Configuration.h`.

  Then you can select which extruders will be set as `E`
  variable in `G1` commands, by sending `T0`, `T1` and so on.
- If your application require contemporary movement of all axes,
  you can enable the `MIXING_EXTRUDERS` option ([source](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,850119)).

  With that option, you are basically splitting the `E` argument
  between steppers. To set the ratio of your movement, you can give

```
    M163 S0 P0.6    # Set stepper 0 to ratio 0.6
    M163 S1 P0.4    # Set stepper 1 to ratio 0.4
    M164 S2         # Create a virtual stepper with given settings
    T2              # Select the virtual stepper
```

- If you want to configure additional steppers as proper axis,
  check this [commit](https://github.com/DerAndere1/Marlin/commit/0258cc906eda008cd1863be44b05ab6c3a15fdc9).